# How to get unique values in df columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading many excel files. Excel files have this format:

```
       CODE    STATION    TMAX_SC
0      000659  ACOBAMBA   -999.0
1      000659  ACOBAMBA   -999.0
2      000659  ACOBAMBA   -999.0
3      000659  ACOBAMBA     15.8
4      000659  ACOBAMBA     18.4
      ...       ...      ...
20570  000659  ACOBAMBA     19.2
20571  000659  ACOBAMBA     19.2
20572  000659  ACOBAMBA     18.0
20573  000659  ACOBAMBA     16.9
20574  000659  ACOBAMBA     16.0
```

Some dfs have one unique value in CODE column and some dfs have 2 values or maybe more.

I want to get a list with the dfs that have 2 or more values in CODE column. So i'm doing this code:

```
path = "/path/to/file/"
files = os.listdir(path)

files_xls = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in files if f[-3:] == 'xls']

dfs = pd.DataFrame()
stations = pd.DataFrame()

for i in files_xls:
    data = pd.read_excel(i, 'Sheet 1',converters={'CODE':str})
    #print(i,data['CODE'])
    duplicates = {'FILE':[i],
        'CODE':[data['CODE'].drop_duplicates()]}
    duplicates=pd.DataFrame(duplicates)
    stations=stations.append(duplicates)
    dfs = dfs.append(data)
```

But i got this error `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'`

How can i get a list with the dfs that have 2 or more values in CODE column?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which line got that error?  Because I don't believe this code caused that error.

Comment: And by the way, pandas `groupby` function can by used to give you the count for each unique value.  What you're doing is going to show you all the unique values, even if they only occurred once.

Comment: you can probably use [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html) and be like `if data['CODE'].nunique()>=2: ...`

Comment: what is the exact output you want/need: a list of the file names when there are more than 2 different CODE values, maybe with the number of different values or the values themselves? or you want a dataframe with the concatenation of all these dataframes with more than 2 different CODES? or something else?

Comment: @Ben.T yes i need this: A list of the file names when there are more than 2 different CODE values, maybe with the number of different values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comment you need *A list of the file names when there are more than 2 different CODE values, maybe with the number of different values* , I believe you can use [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html) and do:

```
l = [] # for the result
for i in files_xls:
    # get directly the number of unique values in CODE
    n = (pd.read_excel(i, 'Sheet 1', converters={'CODE':str}, 
                       usecols=['CODE'], # just need this columns
                       squeeze=True) # to create a Series instead of a dataframe
         .nunique() # get the number of unique values in the Series CODE column
    )
    if n>1: #if more than a unique CODE in the file
        l.append([i, n]) # append the file name and the number to a list
print(l) 
# or print(pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['file_name', 'Nunique_CODE']))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like: `df.groupby(['CODE']).size().reset_index(name="Count")`

This should give you counts of each code in a new column. Then you can filter count column for >2.

Comment: I don't think OP want the size for each CODE in file, but more how many different CODE there are per file?

Comment: I see, thought groupby + size or count would give that.

Comment: That's right @Ben.T i want how many different CODE there are per file

Comment: @excelguy i got this error: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1. Maybe because i got more than 1 code value in some files.